# SugarORM + Kotlin: Unresovled reference "listAll"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sugarorm

I am trying to use the gorgeous Kotlin and SugarORM in combination for Android development and have my models set up like this:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord

public class Contact : SugarRecord<Contact>() {
    var name : String = ""
    var phoneNumber : String = ""
    var info : String? = null
}
```

Of course I have also changed the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">

    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="database.db" />
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="/* same as package attribute on manifest element */" />

    <activity>…</activity>
</application>
```

Now I'm trying to use the model inside `MainActivity.kt`:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val contacts = Contact.listAll(javaClass(Contact))
    // or val contacts : List<Contact> = Contact.listAll(javaClass(Contact))

    return true
}
```

But getting the error `Unresolved reference: listAll`, meaning the static method call failed for some reason. Same with methods like `find`… did I overlook something?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As those are static methods, you need to call them on the declaring class `SugarRecord`. Your code should be:

```
SugarRecord.listAll(Contact::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

In lack of a better explanation, this seems to be a Kotlin bug. It seems like the static methods are not inherited. Creating a helper class like this:

```
public class ModelHelper {    
    public static List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return Contact.listAll(Contact.class);
    }
}
```

and calling this from the Kotlin code like

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val contacts = ModelHelper.getAllContacts()    
    return true
}
```

works.

Comment: It's not a bug, static methods are not inherited per design.